# Aks nginx domain based routing

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I currently have a loadbalancer with a public static ip and a cluster with a single pod. Also im using nginx to expose the related service to the outside.
Since I need to create a second pod in the same cluster which is also available by the loadbalancer ip i wondered how to set this up.
The first pod created should be availably by test.mydomain.com and the new pod by mydomain.com.
The only thing I found out regarding this setup is domain based routing. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, ingress controller with domain based routing using ingress object should be best suitable option. Single ingress controller on top of load balancer can help you expose multiple services.

Guide to install nginx ingress controler in AKS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli

Sample deployment files with domain based routing ingress objects.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-domain-dot-com
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: test-mydomain-dot-com-service-name
                port: 
                  number: 80
    - host: mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-domain-dot-com-service-name
                port: 
                  number: 80
```